# How can I change my email on clash of clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm using my brother email to play clash of clans, and now I want to change it to use my email. So, How can I change this email?

Comment: [There are a few questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=[clash-of-clans]+account) like this on the site. Have you looked at any of those? If not, have a look and see if ay answer your query. If they do, Leave an upvote so others in future can also find the answer they seek!

Comment: Email address is the the sole identifier of an account and therefore cannot be changed. What you are asking is, how you can play the game with your own account, which was already asked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an iOS? Android? PC?

If you're using Android, it should be possible with Google+ same goes with PC.

To do this on Google+, you have to enter the app and log out of the Google+ account then use your own (if you have one).

I am not very sure how to do this with an iOS though.

I hope I helped you out if you're using an Android =), this has worked for me.